# PostgreSQL pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a database backup using the command

```
pg_dump -U vdc(old db) | psql vdc_bak.sql(backup db);
```

What's wrong with the syntax here?

It tells "syntax error near pg_dump"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask especially the "Be specific" section.

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a valid PostgreSQL error message

Comment: I wonder if there's a circle of Hell where tortured souls are forced to spend an eternity debugging Enterprisey applications whose only error messages are "Oops, that didn't work..." and "Fall down, go boom!"

Comment: I recommend you to add details and ask it to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JackManey: If anything Hell contains tortured souls forced to debug applications based only on bug reports containing "doesn't work" in the full knowledge, that there actually _are_ better error messages but those messages simply are not told.

Answer (score 40):

You still don't show us the big picture, but the "syntax error" seems to indicate that you run that from within a SQL client tool (psql, pgAdmin, ...)

`pg_dump` and `psql` are *commandline* programs, not SQL statements.

You need to run them from the command prompt (aka shell)

Additionally the *(old db)* parameter is completely wrong. The database is not put into brackets for pg_dump, e.g:

```
pg_dump -U user1 dbname_old_db | psql -U user2 dbname_new_db
```

Again: you have to run this from the command prompt, not from within a SQL tool

Comment: I had the same issue.  I was in psql and had to \q to get back to the shell then run it.

Answer (score 10):

From the error message `syntax error near pg_dump` and the fact that you ended your command line with a semicolon, it looks like you are trying to run `pg_dump` from *within* psql.

This won't work. You need to run your command at the shell (e.g. `bash`) prompt.

(As an aside, providing the text of your error message (syntax error near pg_dump) was pivotal in diagnosing this issue. Your original question did not include it, and no-one was able to help. Once you added the text, you had an answer within a few minutes.)