# Getting Started / Logging in to PSQL in Windows

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm new to psql and trying to create a back-up via pg_dump on a windows system, but I seem to be falling at the first hurdle. I can't get to the right place to run the commands.

I can access psql via two options:

1, via the windows start menu I can access 'SQL Shell (psql). Once the programme opens press enter through the lines:
    `Server [localhost]:`
`Database [postgres]:`
    `Port [5432]:` `Username [postgres]:`

After this I seem to have access to the postgres database, but I cannot run pg_dump from here. I enter: `pg_dump -U postgres -d sample > sample_db_dump.sql;` but this returns an error: `syntax error at or near "pg_dump`.

The second way I access psql is via the 'psql' application in the postgresql folder. When I open this I'm asked for a password, which I cannot get past and I've tried all my passwords, so am confused here.

Any helps how to get past this is appreciated, everything I've seen online about running pg_dump seems to start when you're already in the right place to do so.

Many thanks

Comment: `pg_dump` is a command line program. You need to open a console (`cmd.exe`) from there you can start `pg_dump` (and of  course `psql` and all other command line tools for Postgres). See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9382821/330315 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7265704/330315 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22625162/330315

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I'm still prompted to enter a password when I run pg_dump from the command line. I enter the password and it says that password authentication for user - and then my windows username. So it's trying to log me into postgres with my windows username, which is part of the trouble I'm having.

Comment: Then specify the proper **postgres** user using the `-U` parameter switch for `pg_dump`

Comment: Ok many thanks - that's worked