# psql: Copy psql database from one account to another account

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have access to two accounts A1 and A2 on psql server, where we login through

```
psql -U user_name
```

And have a database say DB. And only A1 has access to DB. The database DB has around 30+ non-empty tables inside it, where the tables are connected to each other through some constraints.

I wanted to create a copy of database DB say DB' for account A2 as well, which will have same set of non-empty tables inside them and with same set of constraints between the tables.

Now, if I will try to create DB' for the account A2, then there are huge possibilities of mistakes. So, is there any easy way exists other than manually creating.

Comment: `pg_dump -U user_name -d db` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383807/16697024 @a_horse_with_no_name is it work in this scenario work?

Comment: You can even do it via pure SQL command in Postgres. "CREATE DATABASE DB2 OWNER A2 TEMPLATE DB;" Check: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createdatabase.html